# Select max date of customer and retain the number of rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to know the max(date) of group by customer and still retain the number rows from the base table.

| customer_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 |
| 1 | 10-01-2022 |
| 1 | 15-02-2022 |

The result that I’m looking for

| customer_id | date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 15-02-2022 |
| 1 | 10-01-2022 | 15-02-2022 |
| 1 | 15-02-2022 | 15-02-2022 |

Query tried

```
Select * 
From table_1
Group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: "Number of rows" for each customer?  Or what?

Answer (score 1):

See if you like this; it comes close to answering your question literally:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       COUNT(*) AS num_rows,
       MAX(date) AS latest
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY customer_id;
```

But, if you want to show the other columns for all the rows for each customer, it gets messier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the values of all columns that exist in the table, and on top of that, you want to fetch the max date for each customer.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT MAX(date) 
          FROM tbl t2 
         WHERE t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id) AS max_date
FROM tbl t1;
```